# Como puedo interactuar con el checkbox dentro de un ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

Modifique el `ListBoxItem` para agregar un `Checkbox`.

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="check" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>    
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

El objetivo es eliminar todos los **Item** marcado, pero no se como aceder al **CheckBox** para verificar si esta marcado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach(ListBoxItem listBoxItem in ListaPNT.Items)
            {
                listBoxItem.check.IsCheck();
            }

        }
```

Agredesco su pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no estás usando el patrón MVVM por lo que mi respuesta será en base a eso y dejo claro que es mucho más fácil con MVVM:

Lo primero es dejar claro que NO por clickear el checkbox se va a cambiar el item seleccionado, puedes clickear el checkbox del último elemento de la lista pero si el seleccionado es el primero, seguirá siéndolo, debes tener cuidado con eso.

Lo ideal en estos casos es que los controles de tipo listas los llenes con una Lista de objetos, por ejemplo de Personas, en este caso sería `List<Personas>`, bindear el checkbox y demás controles a las propiedades del objeto, por ejemplo el checkbox iría bindeado a un `boolean` que indicará si está o no marcado, y cuando quieras borrar solo recorres la lista eliminando los que estén marcados y finalmente actualizas la vista en pantalla (porque no se hará automático), pero esto te traerá un problema y es que no recorrer una lista en pantalla y borrar al mismo tiempo porque los index cambian y te dará error, por eso recomiendo usar una lista temporal para ayudar.

Ahora bien, si quieres ahorrarte eso y que el asunto te funcione sin importar como, puedes acceder al checkbox usando el siguiente ejemplo que he preparado:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Persona> lista_personas = new List<Persona>(); 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lista_personas.Add(new Persona("PERSONA 1"));
            lista_personas.Add(new Persona("PERSONA 2"));
            lista_personas.Add(new Persona("PERSONA 3"));
            lista_personas.Add(new Persona("PERSONA 4"));
            lista_personas.Add(new Persona("PERSONA 5"));
            lista.ItemsSource = lista_personas;
        }

        private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Persona> lista_temporal = new List<Persona>(); 

            foreach (Persona item in lista.Items)
            {
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(FrameworkElement)lista.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)listBoxItem.Template.FindName("check", listBoxItem);
                bool borrar = checkBox.IsChecked == true ? true : false;

                if (!borrar)
                {
                    lista_temporal.Add(item);
                }
            }

            lista_personas = lista_temporal;
            lista.ItemsSource = lista_personas;
        }      
 
    }
```

Si te fijas, he asumido que tienes una lista de objetos, que la asignas en el constructor y otras cosas, pero tu puedes ir adaptando el ejemplo.

Lo importante acá es que cuando quieras borrar vas al código del método `btnBorrar_Click` y ahí puedes ver como acceder a lo que hay dentro de tu Template (yo tuve que borrar el `BaseOn` en el `Style` para que compilara).

El proceso es obtener el item actual, obtener su representación, buscar el elemento que se llama "**check**" y verificar su estado, OJO! Que lo cambies en pantalla no significa que se cambie en la lista de origen (lista_personas).

Luego los que NO están marcados para borrar los pongo en una lista temporal, y al final esa lista temporal la uso para actualizar la lista de origen y luego esa lista de origen la asigno nuevamente al `ListBox` para que la pantalla se refresque.

Sé que para alguien avanzado es un PÉSIMO ejemplo, pero reitero que estoy omitiendo MVVM y patrones en general, solo hago que funcione.